# Codeigniter-Ajax i need to return more than one rows and how to access it in my view file

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

when i click on the 'invoice number' in my 'purchase list' i will need to open up a collapsible table that will list the products list matching the invoice no 
I am using jquery to open up a collapsible table and Ajax to retrieve the data

MY VIEW FILE: I am using AJAX to retrieve the data

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".listproduct".click(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=site_url("purchasecont/getproductlist"; ?>',
        data: {'data' : value} ,
        success:function(result){

               $('#invoiceno').html(result['invoiceno']);
               $('#productname').text(result['productname']);
               $('#price').text(result['price']);


        }
    });
 $(".collapse".collapse('toggle');

});
});
</script>
```

MY CONTROLLER FILE : i will be retrieving more than one row from the table

```
public function getproductlist(){
//check if is an ajax request
if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    //checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
    if($this->input->post('data')){

        //query in your model you should verify if the data passed is legit before querying
         $data = $this->purchasemod->getproductlist($this->input->post('data'));
         $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
        return $data;
                }
}
}
```

MY MODEL FILE : i will be retrieving more than one row from the table

```
public function getproductlist($q){
  $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('purchaseprolist');
   $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.invoice' , $q);
    $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price != ',0,FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get();
 foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
    return $row;
  }

  }
```

Comment: kindly help me! i have a error on that

Answer (score 0):

`return $row;` inside of a loop will return only one row.

Instead of:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    return $row;
}
```

Just do:

```
return $query->result();
```